# openpyxl не может выдать список названия страниц

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

openpyxl с помощью load_worbook и get_sheet_names отлично отрабатывает на тестовом файле, но когда нужно применить это к нужному файлу, выдаёт ошибки:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/emedyanik/PycharmProjects/entryToTheDatabase/readFromXL.py", line 22, in <module>
    main = Main()
  File "C:/Users/emedyanik/PycharmProjects/entryToTheDatabase/readFromXL.py", line 10, in __init__
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/emedyanik/Desktop/writeToDatabase/toolbase.xlsm')
  File "C:\Users\emedyanik\AppData\Local\Continuum\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 274, in load_workbook
    for c in find_charts(archive, rel.target):
  File "C:\Users\emedyanik\AppData\Local\Continuum\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\reader.py", line 48, in find_charts
    drawing = SpreadsheetDrawing.from_tree(tree)
  File "C:\Users\emedyanik\AppData\Local\Continuum\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\emedyanik\AppData\Local\Continuum\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\emedyanik\AppData\Local\Continuum\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 100, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fLocksText'
```

Я так понимаю, что файл слишком сложный для этого, какие есть варианты, чтобы это обойти?

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550059/5909792

Comment: файл очень большой и хотелось бы найти другое решение, если оно существует

Comment: можно попробовать использовать модуль `xlrd`. PS если хотите более детальный совет, то попробуйте выложить небольшой Excel файл, который позволил бы воспроизвести проблему...